# Recommended packages for Intranet Analytics?

Tags: analytics, intranet

I'm  looking for someone who can provide some information on analytics for an intranet site. The intranet site has limited access to the internet and ideally there should be no tranmission of analytics information externally.

Are there any open source or else well constructed analytics packages that I can consider for this purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: serverfault would be more appropriate. This isn't about programming.

Comment: Here's a recent review of on premises web analytics software packages. There are a handful of open source and commercial options:

http://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/website-analytics-software-review

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) if you want something Open Source and easy to use and understand (for, say, intranet editors). It does not use server logs and instead tracks visits by means of a piece of javascript you would insert in pages that you'd like to track.

We use it in combination with Awstats for our intranet.

Comment: This looks good, thanks. I'll post back and let you know how I get on with it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you use Piwik you can export data from GA using [Google2Piwik](http://clearcode.cc/offer/open-source-projects/google2piwik/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out awstats.  I implemented it a few months ago.  It's perl-based but does a fairly good job of analyzing your IIS or similar web server.

http://www.bing.com/search?q=awstats

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Logparser is sufficient for your needs: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

It doesn't offer out-of-box functionality like awstats but you might find it useful for other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of different options for commercial stuff but can be somewhat costly.

Perhaps you might want to check out something like sawmill ....

Thomas